# When cards expand hover bottom row

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of cards , on click , I'm expanding card with description . The problem is that when it expands it moves down bottom row . I need to hover bottom cards without moving it . I recreated my problem in sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-star-cov3x

here how it supposed to be by design:

[image]

thats what I got, when card expands it moves down bottom row:

[image]

Comment: Your sandbox code doesn't show the layout and the click effect? In general, when you want some content to stop affecting the position of other parts of the page, you need `position: absolute`. I've made similar layouts by adding a 'liner' element inside each cell, and then setting it to absolute on hover. If you can fix your sandbox example, I can give you the exact code.

Comment: use position: absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this three properties in your .expand-card class,

```
 position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    background: white;
```

Your .expand-card class should be

```
.expand-card {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    background: white;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
}
```

Then it will work fine.

And you can explore more on css property positions

Comment: thanks for your answer It works fine, but there is a problem . All cards expanding in left top corner. Check sandbox, I updated with your code

Comment: Yea i noticed that now. But what you can do is, add an evelope on your cards and then it works. Check out the working page https://sbv70.csb.app/

Comment: You can check the updated code @ https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-lehmann-sbv70

Answer (score -1):

On hover css you need to use position properties.
Example:

```
class:hover{
   position:absolute;
}
```

But also you need to keep position relative to the parent class so card can not move or shake.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question asked, and doesn't explain the question it is answering.